# How to anonymize all passwords in a file in bash

Tags: string, bash, replace, sed, awk

Assume you have a large configuration file containing passwords and other classified data. The file may change in the future. I would like to substitute this kind of data with placeholders, e.g. `***` using bash to create a version of the current config without containing the classified information.

The file does has the form:

```
user_foo=Foo
foo_pwd=12345
user_bar=Bar
bar_password_x=42
a.passwd=asdf
```

and should be transformed to

```
user_foo=Foo
foo_pwd=***
user_bar=Bar
bar_password_x=***
a.passwd=***
```

Some script accepting a blacklist of strings being contained on the left side of the assignents (e.g., "pwd", "password", "passwd") is maybe the way to do it.

Unfortunately I am no expert in bash but maybe there is an elegant solution based on sed or awk.

Comment: You can only store them well by encrypting them with another password. Other forms could be just by obscurification or obfuscation and could still be decoded without a password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sed:

```
sed -r 's/((pwd|password|passwd)[^=]*=).*/\1***/' input > output
```

Comment: Will work in gnu sed only though. Macs come with the BSD version, which does not support the `-r` option.

Comment: Yeah, there's probably an equivalent for BSD sed, I just couldn't figure it out and went over to my Linux box.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="="; OFS="="; } $1 ~ /pwd|password|passwd/ {$2="***"}1' inputfile
```

For your input, it should emit:

```
user_foo="Foo"
foo_pwd=***
user_bar="Bar"
bar_password_x=***
a.passwd=***
```

Comment: Thanks. I noted that if the password contains "=" itself, it is still contained in the line.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
awk -F= '$1~/pwd|password|passwd/ {$2="***"}1' OFS="="
user_foo=Foo
foo_pwd=***
user_bar=Bar
bar_password_x=***
a.passwd=***
```

Comment: You need to specify `=` as the output separator

Comment: Guess what it'd do if a line in the input reads: `user_foo=pwd`